# Issue with grid responsivity

Tags: html, css

```css
.all {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 20% 80%;
      grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  gap: 1em;
}

.left-side {
  width: 320px;
  height: 869px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 72px;
}

.left-side .menu {
  padding-top: 51px;
  padding-left: 26px;
}

.left-side .menu h6 {
  height: 12px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  color: #9fa7bb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.left-side .menu-items {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.left-side .menu-items span {
  height: 31px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.47;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #242b39;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.left-side .menu-items li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left-side .menu-items li:hover {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #f1f4f8;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: -18px;
}

.left-side .menu-items img {
  -o-object-fit: contain;
     object-fit: contain;
}

.right-side h2 {
  margin-top: 56px;
  width: 556px;
  height: 37px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 31px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: -0.37px;
  color: #000000;
}

.right-side .options {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.right-side .add button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #407cff;
  border-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
   <section class="all">
    <section class="left-side">
        <section class="menu">
            <h6>Site Admin</h6>
            <ul class="menu-items">
                <li><img src="./images/online.png" class="icons"><span>Customer Overview</span></li>
                <li><img src="./images/list-dot.png" class="icons"><span>Reports</span></li>
                <li><img src="./images/file-add.png" class="icons"><span>File transcodings</span></li>
                <li><img src="./images/notification.png" class="icons"><span>Notification center</span></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </section>

    <section class="right-side">
        <h2>Customer Overview</h2>

        <section class="options">
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Customer or ID">
            </div>

            <div class="add">
                <button>+</button>
            </div>
            
        </section>
    </section>
    </section>
```

Hello,

I need a advice how to make better and responsive grids. I run into a problem when I make simple layout of left menu and right content side. I think I did it right, but when I get to smaller sizes the right side gets into the left one. Is there some way to solve it so it could be responsive?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I am following correctly but as the screen gets smaller and smaller, it has to compensate to try and fit everything into one column. This results in overlapping of elements. It may be easier to try using media queries at a specific viewport in order to resolve this issue. Otherwise, you can try making elements smaller, adding padding/margins to the `.right-side` side, or increasing the `gap` value for the `.all` element.